# Pass function\class in parameter to static library

Tags: c++, g++, freebsd

The actual question arose, how can one get a class and another function from the main program in the parameters of a function (in a static library)?

For example, this works from the main program, I want to transfer this function to the static library:

```cpp
void CHAR :: Test (LPCHAR attacker, DWORD time) 
   {
       DWORD id = attacker-> GetPlayerID ();
   }
```

LPCHAR - a class in the main program

and this is from the static library:

```cpp
void slibrary :: Test (XXXX attacker, char const * time, YYYY) 
   {
       DWORD id = attacker-> YYYY;
   }
```

LPCHAR:

```
typedef CHAR* LPCHAR;
```

CHAR:

```
class CHAR: public CEntity, public CFSM, public CHorseRider
{
}
```

Where is XXXX - I need to get the `LPCHAR` class, how to do it?

Where YYYY - get `GetPlayerID()` function, how to do it?

Or does it somehow work differently?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with writing static libs, but can you not make the `Test` function a template?

Comment: Add the definition of `CHAR` and `LPCHAR` to the question.

Comment: LPCHAR - custom class

Comment: Which operating system are you running this on?

Comment: FreeBSD 9.2 Release

Comment: I believe your question more-so has to do with how do you pass member methods and class objects to another function to be called, rather than just for use of static library?

Comment: yes, you right.

Comment: "_LPCHAR - custom class_" - Why not add the definition of `CHAR` and `LPCHAR` to the question?

Comment: even though it has nothing to do with it. I still added this ..

Comment: `typedef CHAR* LPCHAR;` is just confusing and doesn't make you type fewer characters either. Just use `CHAR*` when you want a `CHAR*`. Any reason to take the argument as a `CHAR*` instead of a `CHAR&`? What stops you from having the same signature in the library? `void slibrary :: Test (CHAR* attacker, DWORD time) `? What is `YYYY` supposed to be?

Comment: @Qiveq Did my answer work as you wanted?

Comment: not, i am want in another files, function will in static library, and need call this function in main program

Answer (score 0):

The signature in your library isn't the same as in your original code but it seems you'd like to be able to call member functions by using member function pointers. Example:

```
class CHAR {
public:
    DWORD GetPlayerID() { return 1; }
};

class slibrary {
public:
    // YYYY is here a member function pointer 
    void Test(CHAR* attacker, DWORD time, DWORD (CHAR::*YYYY)()) {
        DWORD id = (attacker->*YYYY)();
        std::cout << id << '\n';
    }
};

int main() {
    CHAR a;
    slibrary sl;
    sl.Test(&a, 0, &CHAR::GetPlayerID);
}
```

Output:

```
1
```